# CSS @keyframe, translateX() and rotateY() on both ends

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm trying to make some kind of Mario Kart animation using only CSS, where I basically have a car starting from the left side of the screen going all the way across the screen.

Here is where the problem occurs:
I want the car to basically change direction (so going back from right to left).

This is simply done with an `animation-direction` of `alternate`.
If you picture this, you see that the car is going backwards on the way from left to right.

What I want to do is to mirror it at the end of each path, so that the car turns and faces the opposite direction, which should take up like **0.1s** and can be done using the `rotateY(180deg)`.

I tried to combine several keyframe animations (one for the `translate`, and one for the `rotate`), but that wouldn't work, since my 'car' would just rotate and glitch and wouldn't move at all. I figured that the order of the two transform methods might be the problem, but it still didn't work the other way around.

After that, I tried to combine the two `transform` methods and alternate the animation, which looked somewhat like this:

```
div {
    animation: dirChange 5s linear infinite both alternate;
}

@keyframes dirChange {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(20vw) rotateY(0);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(80vw) rotateY(0);
    }
    90% {
        transform: translateX(80vw) rotateY(.5turn);
    }
    100%{
        transform:translateX(80vw) rotateY(.5turn);
    }
}
```

As you can see I tried to `translate` the car to the end of `80vw` first and tried to apply the `rotateY` afterwards. This looks somewhat okay on the first way from left to right (even though the car rotates a bit early which could easily be fixed using other percentages), but then on the alternate way back, the car of course rotates very early on and basically drives the rest of the way backwards.

So how can I have my car rotate at the end of each way, then keep that rotation for the alternate way and then rotate again at the starting point?
Is this even possible with CSS only or do I need JS?

Comment: Would it help if you use `left`, `right` absolute position to move it and use transform only for rotating?

Comment: Yes this would work, but the problem is that once it rotated at the end, it doesn't stay rotated for the way back...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do it. Here is my solution as it can be seen on my codepen https://codepen.io/xutocode/pen/poNGXam .

```
@keyframes changeDir{
0% {transform: translateX(0vw) rotateY(0);}
49% {transform: translateX(89vw) rotateY(0);}
50% {transform: translateX(90vw) rotateY(.5turn);}
99% {transform: translateX(1vw) rotateY(.5turn);}
100% {transform: translateX(0vw) rotateY(0);}
}
```

The trick was basically to put it all inside one keyframe and then taking the complete cycle (not only the way from left to right, but also the way back). Essentially I then just gave them the 1% from 49 to 50% and 99 to 100% to rotate along the y-axis, resulting in a mirrored car.

Answer (score 0):

Use `to` and `from` instead of percentages.

Comment: I tried that. Could you maybe elaborate on that? My main problem is that once the car rotated at the end it doesn't stay rotated for the way back.

Comment: Maybe attempt using 0%, 1%, 99%, and 100% to handle movement.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your help but none of this seems to work